# Why do proxy servers not allow the use of localhost?

Tags: jquery, ajax, proxy, localhost, reverse-proxy

I'm using the proxy web service [HideMe](https://hide.me/en/proxy) to view a site I've designed.

In my site's code there is an Ajax HEAD call that first check's if http://localhost:3000 is available and then changes the URL in the error clause to a web address before moving on to the next Ajax call that contains a GET request. I like the idea of having two consecutive AJAX calls because I set the first call to synchronous, which allows for loading of a locally stored loader.gif animation in time. It also acts as a bypass for having separate scripts for production and development environments. The alternative URL is on a reverse proxy. This switch works fine when not using a proxy, but when I'm using a proxy I get undefined results with the following being logged to the console:

```
HEAD 
XHR 
https://proxy-nl.hide.me/go.php [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 176ms]

GET 
https://proxy-nl.hide.me/go.php [HTTP/2.0 304 Not Modified 497ms]

GET 
XHR 
https://proxy-nl.hide.me/go.php [HTTP/2.0 200 OK 186ms]

syntax error go.php:1:1
```

If you then click on go.php:1:1, the following error message is returned by the browser:

```
Sorry, this proxy does not allow the requested site (<b>localhost</b>) to be viewed.
```

Why do proxy servers not allow the use of localhost?

Comment: Because the proxy services handles the routing of the request based on the specified URL. It observes a string, and when meeting localhost, there would be unintended consequences and could possibly open up vulnerabilities on their end, long story short, no localhost over proxy's.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Do you think this error would have an impact on user experience? Should I try something else?

Comment: I would perform the check on the serverside as opposed to the client side, I think.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nginx, Meteor and Docker: Proxy SSL redirection does not work on localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190335/nginx-meteor-and-docker-proxy-ssl-redirection-does-not-work-on-localhost)